# Insert progress spinner into splashscreen android

Tags: android

In my android application,i would like to place a progress bar such that it shows the user that the data is getting downloaded  and gets dismissed once the data is loaded.

Is there any way that i can achieve this.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it by AsyncTask class.

In that three steps you have to follow,

1. you have to start the ProgreesDialog in `onPreExecute()`.
2. `doInBackground()` takes control of the Downloading Progress.
3. `onPostExcecute()` runs after the second step. on that you can dismiss your progressdialog, start the New Activity and finish your splashscreen.

**More Info, check the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). It has a explanation with example code.**

CODE:

```
  private class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
            your_class.this);

    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // do downloading images code here
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
           //start the another activity and then close your current activity here.
        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen.Could you please provide me with any sample code if u have?

Comment: @Reshmi: Please check the documentation link. I mentioned it already in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Praveen.The sample code is to download file from url but what require is download file from local project.Is it possible with the same.

Comment: Sorry if the my doubt is very silly but as i am newbie couldnot make it

Comment: @Reshmi: Hey i added some code snippet. Hope it helps you. and one more thing, when you comment to anybody. comment like this format `@username: your comment`. It wake up the notification for them. it helps to get the quick response. ;)