# change progressdialog background

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

In my android application I am using progress dialog in my splashscreen.
I would like to see only the progressbar with loading message without the background.
Is there any way that I can change the background to transparent in Android?

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

ProgressBar should be placed on the Layout and then you have to set or change the progressbar in your activity.

Beware of setting the background before setting max, min, progress and text or it will not render correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can get it by defining the  progressbar and the text in your xml file and you control it in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

As MGS says, you can put the `<Progressbar>` in your layout xml file itself. Moreover you want to customize your ProgressDialog then you have to study [the CustomDialog Tutorial in the Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). It explains everything about Dialog completely.

Comment: @Praveen.Its for the same purpose as answered by you in below link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740458/insert-progress-spinner-into-splashscreen-android.Here i donot want to use a dialog but a simple progressbar can i do that

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of custom dialog instead of using progress dialog.
Custom dialog will be a better approach to do this .
Follow the [link](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application).
You can also use

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

in the  background property of the parent layout in order to make it transparent.

Hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

make layout .xml file  which you want to display in Dialog then Create Object of Dialog

Dialog dialog = new Dialog(main.this);

1. dialog.setContentView(R.layout."your_layout");
2. dialog.setTitle("This is my custom dialog box");
3. dialog.setCancelable(true);

Answer (score 0):

Create a dialog set set the dialog style to following:

```
  <style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

For ex:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(main.this,R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
dialog.setContentView(<layout>);
```

Just put your progress bar in layout.