# Custom background color for a ProgressDialog

Tags: android, background, progressdialog

I have a progressDialog, that works, but doesn't fit my extetical needs:

[image]

I'd like to make it like this:

[image]

What I tried:

1 - Theming (with both a style only and a style + theme methods), as explained here
The result was AWFUL (I got an extra border around the dialog in the same blue 
color and an extra padding around the title with that default grayish color)

In other words, i got somethig like this:

[image]

2 - Extending the ProgressDialog Class and giving it a custom layout, without 
any success

I got a bunch of different errors and I made a big mess trying to fix this one, 
this other one, ... no way!!

Now, i know that someone has done it before... Show me the light, please!!

Some code, to show you how I make it actually

In declarations I have:

```
ProgressDialog pbrDlg = null;
```

Then in a menu selection I have:

```
case R.id.mnuBack:
case R.id.mnuRest:
{
    // Backup or Restore
    // Instantiate a new progress dialog
    pbrDlg = new ProgressDialog(ACT_Base.this);

    // Spinner (wheel) style dialog
    pbrDlg.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

    String str = "";
    if (itm.getItemId() == R.id.mnuBack)
    {
        pbrDlg.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_save);
        pbrDlg.setTitle(getString(R.string.data_save));
        str = "save";
    }
    else
    {
        pbrDlg.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_revert);
        pbrDlg.setTitle(getString(R.string.data_load));
        str = "load";
    }
    pbrDlg.setMessage(getString(R.string.data_msg));

    // Display the dialog
    pbrDlg.show();

    // Start the async task
    new Data_ImpEx_Task(str).execute();

    break;
}
```

Comment: Any help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401061/change-progressdialog-and-alertdialog-background-in-android

Comment: What is the minimal API level you are planning to support?

Comment: I'm supporting API Level 8+ (From 2.2 to ... infinite)

Comment: @Niko no... it's not unblocking my situation...

Comment: you make an enormous amount of very minor edits even to posts that need more work. Please, when you edit a question, make sure to improve any shortcomings you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally succeeded in solving my problem.

I used a `DialogFragment` which I customized in each part to make it look like a
`ProgressDialog`.

After all, I am doing the same for showing Alerts and Confirmations, so...

This is the result I got:

[image]

I just have to virate the icon to a blueish flavour and it's nearly perfect.