# android start activity and keep running previous

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I would like to call splashScreen activity while current activity is been executed. Once current activity finishes its load, finish splashScreen activity. How can I call one activity and keep executing current activity? Thank you.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(TabBarActivity.this, splashScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        cicle();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do the "loading" in splash activity instead, whenever the loading ends, launch the next activity. There is no need for something that complex

Answer (score 2):

Have a ProgressBar load in your SplashScreen activity via an AsyncTask. Keep updating the progressbar in that activity and once the loading is fully completed, you can start a new activity in maybe..postExecute() method.

You can refer to this: [Progressbar in Splashscreen android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3740458/735675)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest this:

1. Make the Splashscreen the entry point of your application.
2. From the SplashscreenActivity execute the long-running task in the background (see AsyncTask and its doInBackground() method)
3. When that's finished, switch to the next activity and transfer the background operation result (intent.putExtra...)

Comment: Actually you don't even need to run the task in the background, but maybe it's more safer because the system may think your application hanged up. Please tell me if it does.

Comment: Its good idea to run initializations in AsyncTask, otherwise ANR will show up. But its important that AsyncTask-s must not be run simultaneously